# Add class every second but only for 5 seconds. [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, class, settimeout, setinterval

I want to create a function that will add a class every second but after 5 seconds the function will end. This function should add an active class to one of the five lights.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```js
    const lights = document.querySelectorAll('.light');

    let active = true;

    const headFunction = () => {
        lightsFunction();
    }

    const lightsFunction = () => {
        if (active) {
            for (let i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
                lights[i].classList.add('on');
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
                lights[i].classList.remove('on');
            }
        }
    }
    headFunction();
```

I would also like to ask about one thing. How to make the function with counting time run only after finishing the function by turning on the lights? That is, the lights go out, and only then the counting starts.

Comment: You have 5 lights - as I understand it the first light should go on for a second then switch off and then the second light should go on for a second and so on. Is this correct? If so there may be a simpler way of doing it without JS. Could you show us your CSS?

Comment: The first second passes, the first light comes on and stays on, then another second and the next light comes on. When the last light is on, they all go out and the time starts counting up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with different delays to add and remove the classes.

By adding an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) you can check if you are done turning all the lights on/off.

```js
const LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS = 'light--on';
const ACTIVE_TIME = 1000; // milliseconds

const lights = document.querySelectorAll('.light');

const turnAllLightsOff = (lights) => {
  lights.forEach((light) => {
    light.classList.remove(LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS);
  });
}

lights.forEach((light, index) => {
  // Turn light on
  setTimeout(() => {
    light.classList.add(LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS);
    
    // Check if it's the last light
    if(index === lights.length - 1) {
      // Wait a bit before turning the lights off
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Turn all lights off
        turnAllLightsOff(lights);
        
        console.log('Finished...');
      }, ACTIVE_TIME);
    }
  }, index * ACTIVE_TIME);
});
```

```css
.light {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

.light--on {
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
```

**If you want to show a single light at a time:**

```js
const LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS = 'light--on';
const ACTIVE_TIME = 1000; // milliseconds

const lights = document.querySelectorAll('.light');

lights.forEach((light, index) => {
  // Turn light on
  setTimeout(() => {
    light.classList.add(LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS);
  }, index * ACTIVE_TIME);
  
  // Turn light off
  setTimeout(() => {
    light.classList.remove(LIGHT_ACTIVE_CLASS);
    
    // Check if it's the last light
    if(index === lights.length - 1) {
      console.log('Finished...');
    }
  }, (index * ACTIVE_TIME) + ACTIVE_TIME);
});
```

```css
.light {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

.light--on {
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
```

Comment: It looks great, but I guess I misinterpreted what I mean. 1 second passes, the first light is on and stays on, then the next one and the next ones are on (then both are on) and so on until the last one lights up. (here will be another setTimeout of 1-2 seconds to see all 5 light up) Then they all go out.

Comment: @DARKVerbalCentaurPL I've added an extra snippet which does this now